# Definition of addition of vectors

Tags: vectors

I know that a vector is an arrow defined by its magnitude and direction. The addition of two vectors is defined by the triangle law of addition. But why is it defined in this way? Is there a specific a reason to define addition of vectors in such a weird way.(Yes, it seems to me a little0 weird.)

Comment: Yes there are good reasons to define addition of vectors by joining the start of the second arrow to the end of the first one. It is actually the most natural way in my opinion. For example, you can add displacement vectors, velocity vectors, acceleration vectors, vectors within vector fields etc etc and get the most useful results. What to you would be a natural/"not weird" way of adding vectors?

Comment: Probably the simplest example is addition of two displacement vectors. If my initial displacement from the origin is $-2$ **i** and then I walk with a displacement of **i** + **j** from my initial position, then the displacement vector of my final position from the origin is  $-2$ **i** +  **i** + **j**.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I think that vectors are used to model displacement because it just adds like vector. Vector addition must be defined before this.

Comment: @AdamRubinson or it goes like this "we observes that displacement add differently that ordinary numbers this  we created new mathematical object to describe that"

Comment: Well strictly speaking vectors are not *defined* by the triangle rule, although they do obey that rule. First the definition of a Vectors Space is established, and then a vector is defined as any points/member of the vector space. But I feel like I'm not really understanding your question, so I will let someone else take over. I will just say that in order to understand what a vector/ vector space is, it certainly helps to be aware of the triangle law of vector addition...

Comment: Are you familiar with any applications of vectors? For example, if you are on a boat traveling at $12$ knots eastward and the current is flowing at $2$ knots toward the south, how would you calculate the speed and trajectory of the boat?

Comment: @JohnDouma We can calculate it by assigning boat travel and current a vector and then adding them by triangle law. But for this it must be defined before.

Comment: For vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ the addition is defined by adding the corresponding components. For example, in 2D (n=2), $(a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$. The triangle law is a consequence of this and the definition of Euclidian distance: $|(a,b)|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: @VedantChhapariya That's the cause of your confusion. Concrete problems in mathematics motivate our definitions and abstractions, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

What you mention as a vector comes from more of a physics intuition. Vectors in that sense describe physical notions like forces, velocities and accelerations. If you're asking where the definitions of the 'triangle law' or parallelogram law come from, it's that they reflect the world we live in. It's pretty straightforward to realize that when two physical quantities (like velocity, acceleration etc.) act at one point, the result does not equal the sum of their magnitudes.

To picture this imagine paddling at 2km/h against a river flowing at 10km/h. The result isn't that you go at 12km/h, but rather you move **backwards** at 8km/h. This physical reality lead us to define vector addition (at least in this context) as respecting these triangle laws and parallelogram laws.

Like others have alluded to in the comments, once we generalize, vectors are no longer associated with the physical entity you're familiar with, but are abstract elements of some **vector space** which may have varying definitions of what vector addition ''looks like.''